# How to sketch the graph of $\varphi(X)=d(X,A)+d(X,B)$ when $A$ and $B$ are not given?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

> $A,B$ are points in an axis, disposed in this order. Sketch the graph
>   of the following function:
>
> $$\varphi(X)=d(X,A)+d(X,B)$$

$d(A,B)$ is the distance from point $A$ to point $B$.

I'm confused with this question: The values of $A$ and $B$ are not given, I had some guesses but I feel they are not functional, for example: Presuming any arbitrary values for $A$  and $B$ such that $A<B$, for example $A=2$ and $B=3$, then I would have:

$$\varphi(1)=d(1,2)+d(1,3)$$

$$\varphi(2)=d(2,2)+d(2,3)$$

$$...$$

And then presuming new arbitrary values under the given condition:

$$\varphi(1)=d(1,3)+d(1,4)$$

$$\varphi(2)=d(2,3)+d(2,4)$$

$$...$$

But this seems to be really awkward, if I were to find values for $A$ and $B$ in $\mathbb{R}$ for this graph, I would be screwed (I guess).

I feel this isn't the purpose of the exercise, what should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mark points $A$ and $B$ on the $x$-axis, with $A<B$. Let $y_0=d(A,B)$. Clearly $\varphi(A)=\varphi(B)=y_0$, so you now have two points on your graph: $\langle A,y_0\rangle$, and $\langle B,y_0\rangle$. Now try to answer the following questions in terms of $y_0$ and $X$.

- What is $\varphi(X)$ if $A<X<B$?
- What is $\varphi(X)$ if $X<A$?
- What is $\varphi(X)$ if $X>B$?

If you answer these correctly, you can sketch in the graph of $\varphi$. It has the same basic shape no matter what $A$ and $B$ are.

**Added:** Now that you’ve worked out most of it, here’s a rough sketch of the graph:

```
         \                                    /  
          \                                  /  
           \                                /  
            \                              /  
             \____________________________/  









_________________________________________________________________  
             A                            B
```

The line at the bottom is the $x$-axis. The horizontal segment of the graph is at height $y_0=B-A$. The slopes of the other two parts of the graph are $-2$ and $2$.

Comment: I tried to examine it with Mathematica by doing $f(X)=X+10+X+20$, ploting the function with values from $0$ to $30$ - I've obtained a line, is this it?

Comment: I was unable to think without assuming values to $A$ and $B$.

Comment: @Gustavo: No, the graph is only piecewise linear. If you’re going to look at specific values of $A$ and $B$, calculate $\varphi(X)$ by hand for several values of $X$ in each of my three cases and try to see what’s going on.

Comment: You really need to think about it in general. Suppose that $A<X<B$; then $d(A,X)=X-A$, right? What’s $d(X,B)$? What’s $\varphi(X)$?

Comment: Oh, I guess I got it. Let me try a little more.

Comment: Until now I've figured this:

$$\varphi(X) = \begin{cases}
(A-X)+(B-X) & \text{if }X<A<B \\
(X-A)+(B-X) & \text{if }A<X<B \\
(X-A)+(X-B) & \text{if }A<B<X \\
\end{cases}$$

But I'm still unable to sketch the graph.

Comment: @Gustavo: Those are right, but they can be written in slightly more useful form. You can simplify the middle one to get rid of $X$ altogether. The others can be rewritten as $2(A-X)+(B-A)$ and $2(X-B)+(B-A)$, which makes sketching the graph much easier.

Comment: Oh, I understand it now. The strange part for me was that I didn't know what to do with $A$ and $B$.